# Stretching treeview items width to parent container in CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, treeview

I am working on treeview component for left side menu (see screenshot):

[image]

All items in tree view must be selectable. I set width 100% for items and when I select item in tree width of highlighted region is less than left side panel:

[image]

But width of highlighted region to be equal to width of left side panel. I know that it can be achieved with margin and padding manipulations for highlighted region e.g.:

```
{
margin: 0 -400px;
padding: 0 400px;
}
```

But it leads to horizontal scrollbar:

[image]

Are there any "clever" ways to make highlighted region stretch to the container(left side panel)?

Comment: Do you have a code of what you have tried?

Comment: @cakan Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/gf2pa4qn/ . It is messy because I copy and paste markup from the page but the problem is visible here. I try to prepare simple fiddle later if the problem will not be solved

Answer (score 0):

Each child should fit inside its parent when `width: 100%` and/or `max-width: 100%` Some, like LI, do not.

To get the result you want each item needs rules:

- `white-space: nowrap` (so it won't wrap to next line)
- `overflow: hidden` (to chop off excess text)
- `width: 100%` (to stretch to parent)

See below snippet for two examples: with UL/LI and DIV's

```css
html,
body {
  /*UPDATE*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit
}
/* { outline: 1px dotted red } /* for debug */

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.side-panel {
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)
}
ul,
.treeview {
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
li,
.item {
  height: 23px; /*ADD*/
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px 0; /*ADD*/
}
li:hover,
.item:hover { /*ADD*/
  height: 23px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px dashed cornflowerblue;
  cursor: pointer
}
li:nth-child(even),
.item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1)
}
li:nth-child(odd),
.item:nth-child(even) {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)
}
```

```html
<div class="side-panel">
  <h3>example with UL/LI</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>some item 1</li>
    <li>some item 2</li>
    <li>some item 3</li>
    <li>some item 4fgdfg g</li>
    <li>some item 5 sad d fd</li>
    <li>some item 6 sdtresertg zdf dfsfd</li>
    <li>some item 7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="side-panel">
  <h3>example with DIV's</h3>
  <div class="treeview">
    <div class="item">some item 1</div>
    <div class="item">some item 2</div>
    <div class="item">some item 3</div>
    <div class="item">some item 4fgdfg g</div>
    <div class="item">some item 5 sad d fd</div>
    <div class="item">some item 6 sdtresertg zdf dfsfd</div>
    <div class="item">some item 7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I really do not understand how your solution helps in this case.  I've customized your example with div's http://jsfiddle.net/yzqLgrjb/: added nested treeviews and increased padding a little to make it more clear. Now we have 10px padding for side panel and 10px for each tree view. You will see that width of tree view items is less than width of side panel but I nedd to have it equal.

Comment: When I get it right, you need to remove the `.treeview` padding (was just there for the demo, anyway) or change to `padding: 0` (in case of UL), i'll adjust my answer to reflect this... Default most developers add `UL,LI {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 }` to prevent unwanted HTML-default behaviour.

Comment: Your fiddle, with my new code will work when you remove the `.item` class from items that have sub-items. For example 'some item 7'. Check my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/renevanderlende/yzqLgrjb/7/)

Comment: Actually I need padding for tree view content - it shows hierarchical structure and that is the main problem. How can I stretch tree view items width to side panel width and save visual hierarchy? Keep in mind an example with file explorer (e.g. in Windows) when folders nested one into each other and each level shifted a little to the right. I need the same http://screencast.com/t/j7omGZSKD679. Note: I want width to be exactly equal to side panel width only for hovered/selected item but again it shouldn't break tree view hierarchy.